# Is there a way to use str.count() function with a LIST of values instead of a single string?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count the number of times that any string from a list_of_strings appears in a csv file cell.

For example, the following would work fine.

```
import pandas as pd

data_path = "SurveryResponses.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(data_path)

totalCount = 0
for row in df['rowName']:
    if type(row) == str:
       print(row.count('word_of_interest'))
```

However, I would like to be able to enter a list of strings (['str1', str2', str3']) rather than just one 'word_of_interest', such that if any of those strings appear the count value will increase by one.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do any of the answers provided solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of

```
totalCount = 0
words_of_interst = ['cat','dog','foo','bar']

for row in df['rowName']:
    if type(row) == str:
        if sum([word in row for word in words_of_interst]) > 0:
            totalCount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the str accessor:

```
df['rowName'].str.count('word_of_interest')
```

If you need to convert the column to string first, use astype:

```
df['rowName'].astype(str).str.count('word_of_interest')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `list_of_strings = ['str1', str2', str3']` you can try the following:

```
if any(map(lambda x: x in row, list_of_strings)):
    totalCount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to count from an external list

```
strings = ['string1','string2','string3']
sum([1 if sr in strings else 0 for sr in df.rowName])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import io

filedata = """animal,amount
"['cat','dog']",2
"['cat','horse']",2"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(filedata))
```

Returns this dataframe:

```
    animal          amount
0   ['cat','dog']   2
1   ['cat','horse'] 2
```

Search for word cat (looping through all columns as series):

```
search = "cat"

# sums True for each serie and then wrap a sum around all sums
# sum([2,0]) in this case

sum([sum(df[cols].astype(str).str.contains(search)) for cols in df.columns])
```

Returns 2