# Fastest way to get word counts from text using search words from lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I'm actually trying to make a rudimentary classifier so I'd be OK with an NLTK solution but my first couple of attempts at this have been with Pandas.

I have a couple of lists that I want to check the text for and get word counts on, and then return an ordered

```
import pandas as pd
import re
fruit_sentences = ["Monday: Yellow makes me happy.  So I eat a long, sweet fruit with a peel.",
                                "Tuesday: A fruit round red fruit with a green leaf a day keeps the doctor away.",
                                "Wednesday: The stout, sweet green fruit keeps me on my toes!",
                                "Thursday: Another day with the red round fruit.  I like to keep the green leaf.",
                                "Friday: Long yellow fruit day, peel it and it's ready to go."]
df = pd.DataFrame(fruit_sentences, columns = ['text'])
banana_words = ['yellow', 'long', 'peel']
apple_words = ['round', 'red', 'green leaf']
pear_words = ['stout', 'sweet', 'green']

print(df['text'].str.count(r'[XYZ_word in word list]'))
```

Here is where the code blows up because the str.count() does not accept a list.

The end goal is to have a returned list of tuples like this:

```
fruits = [('banana', 5), ('pear', 6), ('apple', 6)]
```

Yes, I could iterate over all the lists to do this but it seems like I just don't know enough Python rather than Python doesn't know how to handle this elegantly.

I found this question but it looks like everyone answered it incorrectly or with a different solution than what was actually asked for, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623830/is-there-a-way-to-use-str-count-function-with-a-list-of-values-instead-of-a-si).

Thank you for helping this newbie figure it out!

Comment: I think banana should be 6 not 5. For your example there are 2 yellow, 2 long and 2 peel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regular expression.

```
# store lists in a dictionary for checking values.
a = {'banana': banana_words, 'apple': apple_words, 'pear':pear_words}

d = {}
# regular expression to match words
regex = '(?<!\S){0}[^\w\s]?(?!\S)'  

for i, j in a.items():
    d[i] = sum([df['text'].str.contains(regex.format(k), case=False).sum() for k in j])

print (d.items())
```

#### Output:

```
[('banana', 6), ('apple', 6), ('pear', 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need:

```
#create dict for names of lists
d = {'banana': banana_words, 'apple': apple_words, 'pear':pear_words}
#create one big list
L =  ' '.join(df['text'])

#count each value of lists and sum in generator
out = [(k, sum(L.count(x) for x in v)) for k,v in d.items()]
print (out)

[('banana', 4), ('apple', 6), ('pear', 6)]
```

If want check lowercase values:

```
#create one big list
L =  ' '.join(df['text']).lower()

#count each value of lists and sum in generator
out = [(k, sum(L.count(x) for x in v)) for k,v in d.items()]
print (out)

[('banana', 6), ('apple', 6), ('pear', 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

*python 3.6.4 / pandas 0.23.4:*

```
import pandas as pd

def count(word_list):
    d = pd.Series(word_list).apply(lambda x: s.str.count(x))
    return d.sum()

fruit_sentences = ["Monday: Yellow makes me happy.  So I eat a long, sweet 
fruit with a peel.",
                        "Tuesday: A fruit round red fruit with a green leaf a day keeps the doctor away.",
                        "Wednesday: The stout, sweet green fruit keeps me on my toes!",
                        "Thursday: Another day with the red round fruit.  I like to keep the green leaf.",
                        "Friday: Long yellow fruit day, peel it and it's ready to go."]

banana_words = ['yellow', 'long', 'peel']
apple_words = ['round', 'red', 'green leaf']
pear_words = ['stout', 'sweet', 'green']

keywords = {'banana': banana_words, 'apple': apple_words, 'pear': pear_words}

s = pd.Series(fruit_sentences)
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
res['type'] = pd.Series(list(keywords.keys()))
res['value'] = pd.Series(list(keywords.values())).apply(lambda x: count(x)).sum(axis=1)
print(list(res.itertuples(index=False, name=None)))
```

*python 2.7.11 / pandas 0.17:*

```
import pandas as pd


def count(word_list):
    d = pd.Series(word_list).apply(lambda x: s.str.count(x))
    return d.sum()


fruit_sentences = ["Monday: Yellow makes me happy.  So I eat a long, sweet fruit with a peel.",
                        "Tuesday: A fruit round red fruit with a green leaf a day keeps the doctor away.",
                        "Wednesday: The stout, sweet green fruit keeps me on my toes!",
                        "Thursday: Another day with the red round fruit.  I like to keep the green leaf.",
                        "Friday: Long yellow fruit day, peel it and it's ready to go."]

banana_words = ['yellow', 'long', 'peel']
apple_words = ['round', 'red', 'green leaf']
pear_words = ['stout', 'sweet', 'green']

keywords = {'banana': banana_words, 'apple': apple_words, 'pear': pear_words}

s = pd.Series(fruit_sentences)

res = pd.DataFrame(columns=[])
res['type'] = pd.Series(keywords.keys())
res['value'] = pd.Series(keywords.values()).apply(lambda x: count(x)).sum(axis=1)

print(list(res.itertuples(index=False)))
```

both will give you:

```
[('banana', 4), ('apple', 6), ('pear', 6)]
```

Comment: tried to test this code and would not run on my PC.  Thank you for trying to help me tho

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I updated my answer, also added python / pandas version just to make sure it runs for you, too.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would use a dictionary look up (super fast), and use Counter O(n) to create the dict.

```
# create a dict of look up values
d = {'banana': banana_words, 'apple': apple_words, 'pear':pear_words}

# preprocess data
df['text'] = df['text'].str.lower()
df['text'] = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]','',x) for x in df['text']]
df['text'] = df.text.str.split()

# flatten the list and create a dict
from collections import Counter 

my_list = [i for s in df['text'] for i in s]
word_count = Counter(my_list)

# final job
output_dict = {k:len([x for x in v if x in word_count]) for k,v in d.items()}
sorted(output_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

[('apple', 2), ('banana', 3), ('pear', 3)]
```

Comment: @SDS sorry my bad, forgot to add import statement here.